# PHP base navigation help

Tags: php

currently i have :

```
$page = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

<li<?php if($page == 'index.php?page=product') print ' id="current"'; ?>><a href="index.php?page=product">Products</a></li>
```

but however when url is something like index.php?page=product&item=100

the class 'id=current' doesn't apply.

any workaround?

thank you for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if($_GET['page'] == 'product')` instead of `if($page == 'index.php?page=product')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.$_GET['page'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to see what is being sent to the $_GET and $_POST vars, you can dump them to the page with this one liner: `<?php echo '<pre>' . print_r($_GET,true) . '</pre>'; ?>`